# A question about MLP-What does this line mean?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, deep-learning, neural-network

I am new to NN. I AM TRYING TO TUNE MY MLP REGRESSOR MODEL. I don't understand what does this line mean "'hidden_layer_sizes': [(100,), (50,100,), (50,75,100,)]" does this mean that we're asking the model to check if the model will perform better in case it has only one hidden layer with 100 hidden points, or two hidden layers(with how many neurons?)or three hidden layers?

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
X, y = scaled_df[[ "Part's Z-Height (mm)","Part's Weight (N)","Part's Volume (cm^3)","Part's Surface Area (cm^2)","Part's Orientation (Support's height) (mm)","Part's Orientation (Support's volume) (cm^3)","Layer Height (mm)","Printing/Scanning Speed (mm/s)","Infill Density (%)"]], scaled_df [["Climate change (kg CO2 eq.)","Climate change, incl biogenic carbon (kg CO2 eq.)","Fine Particulate Matter Formation (kg PM2.5 eq.)","Fossil depletion (kg oil eq.)","Freshwater Consumption (m^3)","Freshwater ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Freshwater Eutrophication (kg P eq.)","Human toxicity, cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Human toxicity, non-cancer (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Ionizing Radiation (Bq. C-60 eq. to air)","Land use (Annual crop eq. yr)","Marine ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)","Marine Eutrophication (kg N eq.)","Metal depletion (kg Cu eq.)","Photochemical Ozone Formation, Ecosystem (kg NOx eq.)","Photochemical Ozone Formation, Human Health (kg NOx eq.)","Stratospheric Ozone Depletion (kg CFC-11 eq.)","Terrestrial Acidification (kg SO2 eq.)","Terrestrial ecotoxicity (kg 1,4-DB eq.)"]]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

mlp = MLPRegressor()
param_grid = {'hidden_layer_sizes': [(100,), (50,100,), (50,75,100,)],
              'activation': ['tanh','relu','lbfgs'],
              'solver': ['sgd', 'adam'],
              'learning_rate': ['constant','adaptive','invscaling'],
              'alpha': [0.0001, 0.05],
              'max_iter': [10000000000],
              'early_stopping': [False],
              'warm_start': [False]}
GS = GridSearchCV(mlp, param_grid=param_grid,n_jobs= -1,cv=5, scoring='r2')
                  
                  
GS.fit(X_train, y_train)

print(GS.best_params_)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are performing a [Grid Search](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) hyper param optimization.
You are trying with:

- Just one hidden layer of 100 units
- Two hidden layers of 50, 100
- 3 hidden layers of 50, 75, 100

Your code will extract all combinations of hyperparameters and tell you which one performed best. If you want to extract only some of these combinations, you could look up RandomSearch.
Otherwise, I suggest the [hyperopt](http://hyperopt.github.io/hyperopt/) library to properly optimize your hyperparams with bayesian methods (e.g. TPE)

Comment: thank you. So after getting the optimum parameters, how can I implement RandomizedSearchCV?

Comment: My suggestion is to FIRST use RandomizedSearch to get a rough estimate of where your optimal parmeters lay. After that, perform a GridSearch (more intensive -_> more precise) around the best values found by your grid search. You can look it up in the [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) docs or search the internet, it's full of tutorials :)

Comment: @JZ0Please mark my answer as correct if you like it :)

Comment: So the code will run the model given one hidden layer of 100 units then will run the code given two hidden layers in which there are 50 hidden points in the first layer and 100 hidden points in the second layer, then finally it will run the model  given three hidden layers in which there are 50 hidden points in the first layer, 75 in the second layer, and 100 hidden points in the third layer?

Comment: It will choose from one of these three setups + one of the three possible activation functions + one of the two possible solvers + .......

Comment: So you will understand that there are many possible combinations, and using GridSearch is very expensive because it will try every single one of them

Comment: No problem @JZ0 enjoy your work

Comment: Anyway you can show me how to implement RandomizedSearchCV for MLP Regressor?

Comment: It's literally the same thing of GridSearch. https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html

Comment: thank you again. Yes I have seen this (thank you for posting it), but what I am confused about is `param_grid = {'hidden_layer_sizes': [(100,), (50,100,), (50,75,100,)]`  shall I keep these numbers for the randomized search then after I get the optimum results use them in my Grid search CV or shall I use larger numbers for the randomized search? (I understand that these numbers depend on the problem I am trying to solve and the number of inputs and outputs I have).

Comment: Lets pretend you have
 `param_grid =  {'param1': [100, 200, 300], 'param2': [1, 4,9,13]} ` and after a Randomized Search you get as you best params 200 and 4. So then you will perform a grid search with
`param_grid =  {'param1': [180, 200, 220], 'param2': [3.5, 4,4.5]} ` to check more in depth

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry to bother you!